# Limit and singular point

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods, proof-explanation

I have a elementary problem but I don't know how to solve it :

1. $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} \dfrac{1}{e^z-1}-\dfrac{1}{z}$, it is indetermine because we have :$\infty - \infty$, according to my research on the web I think that is 1/2 but I don't know how to prove it.
2. singular point of $e^{\frac{1}{z+1}}$

Anybody can help me or give me a clue? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Start by combining the fractions into a single fraction:

$$ \lim_{z \to 0} {\frac{1}{e^z - 1} - \frac{1}{z}} = \lim_{z \to 0} {\frac{z - (e^z - 1)}{z(e^z - 1)}} .$$

Then, use [L'Hopital's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) a couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 2., $z=-1$ is a singular point of $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{z+1}}$. It is in fact as essential singularity because the Laurent series has an infinite number of terms with negative index:
$$
e^{\frac{1}{z+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{1}{z+1}\right)^n= 1+\frac{1}{z+1} + \frac{1}{2!(z+1)^2} + \frac{1}{3!(z+1)^3} + \cdots
$$

Answer (score 0):

The question can be solved with a single applicaton of L'Hospital. As

$$\frac{1+z-e^z}{z(e^z-1)}=\frac{1+z-e^z}{z^2}\frac{z}{e^z-1},$$

the last factor is known to tend to $1$ and can be ignored.

Then by L'Hospital,

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1+z-e^z}{z^2}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1-e^z}{2z}=-\frac12.$$